# mozilla firefox page redirection

Tags: firefox, redirect

When i search for some query and click on any of the results, the link is being redirected to some random sites. What could be the reason behind this? This happens with firefox

Comment: Are you sure you do not mean the part where you go first to google page to register a click and then to the actual link?

Answer (score 0):

When you "search" what sites are you talking about? Google? Yahoo? Stack Overflow?

If all links or a lot of links are being redirected it could quite well be a virus.

If it's only a specific website, that website may have been hacked.